# Flutter chip with label text have changes the label positioning of TextFormField

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-chips, chips

I tried to create a TextFormField component with chip and label text.

code:

```
class BasicChipTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const BasicChipTextField(
      {Key? key,
      this.testKey,
      this.label,
      this.hintText,
      this.suffixIcon,
      this.controller,
      this.textLength,
      this.inputFormatters,
      this.initialValue,
      this.keyboardType,
      this.copyPasteOption,
      this.onChanged,
      this.focusNode,
      this.autoValidateMode,
      this.onTap,
      required this.isDifferentlyAbledSelected,
      required this.selected,
      required this.validator,
      required this.readOnly,
      required this.obSecureText,
      required this.textCapitalization})
      : super(key: key);

  final Key? testKey;
  final bool? copyPasteOption;
  final bool readOnly;
  final bool isDifferentlyAbledSelected;
  final LabelWithMandatoryStar? label;
  final TextCapitalization textCapitalization;
  final List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? initialValue;
  final bool obSecureText;
  final BasicIcon? suffixIcon;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final int? textLength;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final void Function(String)? onChanged;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final AutovalidateMode? autoValidateMode;
  final List<BottomNavListItemDto>? selected;
  final void Function()? onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
      return TextFormField(
          key: testKey,
          onTap: onTap,
          onChanged: onChanged,
          autovalidateMode: autoValidateMode,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          enableInteractiveSelection: copyPasteOption,
          readOnly: readOnly,
          keyboardType: keyboardType,
          textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
          inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
          maxLength: textLength,
          validator: validator,
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14, color: AppColor.black, fontWeight: AppFont.fontWeightRegular
              // Reference to the foundation layer
              ),
          initialValue: initialValue,
          controller: controller,
          obscureText: obSecureText,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            alignLabelWithHint: true,
            filled: true,
            fillColor: AppColor.white,
            counterText: "",
            prefixIcon: prefixIcon(selected, setState),
            label:  label,
            hintText: hintText,
            suffixIcon: suffixIcon,
            hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: AppColor.hintColor),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16, top: 16, left: 15, right: 15),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColor.textFieldBorderColor, width: 0),
            ),
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: AppColor.textFieldBorderColor,
                width: 0,
              ),
            ),
            errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  width: 0,
                  color: AppColor.error,
                )),
            focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                width: 0,
                color: AppColor.error,
              ),
            ),
            errorStyle: const TextStyle(
              height: 0,
              color: AppColor.error,
            ),
          ));
    });
  }

  prefixIcon(List<BottomNavListItemDto>? selected, StateSetter setState) {
    List<BottomNavListItemDto>? selectedTemp = [];
    for(var item in selected!){
      if(item.isSelected!){
        selectedTemp.add(item);
      }
    }
    if (selectedTemp.length < 1) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 5,
          children: selectedTemp.map(
            (item) {
              return Chip(
                  backgroundColor: AppColor.chipGrey,
                  avatar: const Icon(Icons.album_outlined, size: 20),
                  elevation: 0,
                  shadowColor: Colors.teal,
                  label: Text(item.name!, style: TextStyle(color: AppColor.black)),
                  onDeleted: () {
                    setState(() {
                      for(var removedItem in selected){
                        if(removedItem.id == item.id){
                          removedItem.isSelected = false;
                        }
                      }
                      selectedTemp.remove(item);
                    });
                  });
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The above code makes the field like this:

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLIOd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLIOd.png)]

position of the label is changes. Anyone have any idea about this??
I need a TextFormField with exact positioned label. This code doesn't meet the requirement.

Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
child: Wrap(
spacing: 5,
children: selectedTemp.map(
(item) {
return Chip(
backgroundColor: AppColor.chipGrey,
avatar: const Icon(Icons.album_outlined, size: 20),
elevation: 0,
shadowColor: Colors.teal,
label: Text(item.name!, style: TextStyle(color: AppColor.black)),
onDeleted: () {
setState(() {
for(var removedItem in selected){
if(removedItem.id == item.id){
removedItem.isSelected = false;
}
}
selectedTemp.remove(item);
});
});
},
).toList(),
),
);

this is the chip code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of search I got a perfect answer for this :

```
isCollapsed: true
```

by adding the above code to decoration and changed prefixIcon to prefix.